# Proving divisibility of a integer sequence

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

> A sequence of integers $f(n)$ has $f(0) =0$ and satisfies $f(n+2) = a f(n+1)+b f(n)$ for $n \geq 0$, where $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$. For any
> positive integer $k$ with $\operatorname{gcd}(k, b)=1$, show that
> $f(n)$ is divisible by $k$ for infinitely many $n$.

---

Things I have tried so far: (Please correct me if I made any mistakes below, I am self learning :)

1. Rewriting the given relation as $$f(n) = \frac{f(n+2) - a f(n+1)}{b}$$

Now for $f(n)$ to be divisible by $k$ it has to be that $f(n+1) - af(n+1) = mk$ for some $m \in \mathbb{Z}.$ which is equivalent to $f(n+2) \equiv a f(n+1) \operatorname{mod} k$ . Now since $f(n)$ is a integer sequence so $f(n+2) \equiv a f(n+1) \operatorname{mod} b$  but unsure how to proceed from here.

Also $k$ does not divide $b$ so my only observations are $pk + qb = \operatorname{gcd}(k,b)$ or that $bx \equiv 1 \operatorname{mod} k$ has a solution for some unknown $x.$

2. Computing some terms to notice some pattern, however the only term common for the first few is $f(1)$ and no common structures that I can recognise.

---

I fail to proceed, so any hints or tips would be great help. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to solve linear recurrences? The recurrence means you can write $f(n)$ as $u\alpha^n+v\beta^n$ where $\alpha,\beta$ are the roots of $x^2-ax-b,$ $\frac{a\pm \sqrt{a^2+4b}}2.$ Since $f(0)=0,$ $u+v=0.$ Then $u\sqrt{a^2+4b}=f(1). $

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I don't know the techniques to solve linear recurrences. If you can point me to any references, I will make sure to read up on it.

Comment: The case $b=0$ only has to consider $k=1$ and this case all terms work. Let $x_n=(f(n+1),f(n))^t\pmod{k}$. For $b\neq0$ note that the transformation $T:x_{n+1}\mapsto x_n$ is linear and invertible (determinant $-b$ is invertible modulo $k$ since $\gcd(k,b)=1$). If $T$ were eventually periodic $T^{m}x_n=x_{m+n}=x_n=T^nx_{0}$, then $x_0=T^{m-n}x_n$ it would be periodic. Now, the sequence $x_n$ can only take finitely many values. Therefore, it eventually repeats. Since it already takes the value $x_0=(f(1)\mod{k},0)^t$, it will take it again and again. If $x_n=(f(1) \mod{p},0)^t$, then $k|f(n)$.

Comment: @Boxwood I am confident that your solution is correct but I need to supply a elementary proof (elementary as in I am in High School, this is for a scholarship test). So is there a way to show this in an elementary way ?

I don't get the "determinant -b is invertible modulo $k$.." part and the "The case b=0 only has to consider k=1 and this case all terms work" part clearly. Perhaps you can add this comment as an answer.

Comment: You could present it in the following way: You want to study the sequence of remainders of the given sequence, after division by $k$. Observe that the same way that the recurrence allows you to compute $f(n+2)$ from $f(n+1)$ and $f(n)$, we can compute $f(n)$ from $f(n+2)$, $f(n+1)$. But more importantly, if we are told the remainders of $f(n+2)$ and $f(n+1)$ modulo $k$, then we can compute the remainder of $f(n)$ modulo $k$ since $\gcd(b,k)=1$. This observation is nearly all you need. ...

Comment: Next it is all about considering what values can have the remainders, modulo $k$, of two consecutive terms of the sequence. There are only $k^2$ pairs of remainders. So, eventually they start repeating. Now, it could be that there is a chunk of pairs are the beginning and the cycling only starts later. However, the fact that the recurrence of remainders can also be computed backward, it means that the loop also works back. So, the repetition starts from the beginning of the sequence.

Comment: A knowledge that I am assuming you have is that if $\gcd(k,b)=1$, then for every remainder $y$ modulo $k$, there is a unique remainder $x$, such that the remainder of $bx$ modulo $k$ is $y$.

Comment: And well, the closing blow to the problem is that the first pair of remainder is $(f(1)\mod{k}, f(0)\mod{k})$, where $f(0)\mod{k}=0$. So, every time this pair of remainders reappears, we get a remainder $0$ modulo $k$.

Comment: @Boxwood I understood it now! Thank you for making it super clear. That indeed makes sense to me. If you want you can copy paste the comment as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks again~

Comment: You can write up. It would be a good practice. Specially, on how to put the explanation of why the cycling starts from the beginning without making it too abstract-looking like the: $T^mx_n=x_{m+n}=x_n=T^nx_0$ implying $T^{m-n}x_n=x_0$. I don't know myself what would be an ideal presentation for high school of this observation.